# ¿Por qué se usa "hubo" en este párrafo?

Tags: pretérito

¿Por qué se usa *hubo* en este párrafo? ¿Se podría haber usado *había* o no? Si sí, ¿cuál sería la diferencia? Si no, ¿por qué?

> Si bien las enfermedades infecciosas eran causa común de muerte en la Edad Media, **hubo** una que marcó récords. Se trataba de la llamada peste negra, que se estima provocó la muerte de entre un tercio y la mitad de los habitantes de Europa durante el medievo.

Entiendo la diferencia teórica entre los pretéritos indefinido e imperfecto, pero no puedo explicarme cómo funciona la diferencia en este contexto. Lo que me parece muy extraño, según mi entendimiento del asunto, es que siguen hablando de esa enfermedad infecciosa después de haber usado *hubo*. Quizá haya alguien que me pueda explicar.

Comment: Siguen hablando de ella para explicarla en profundidad. Creo que se entiende mejor si reemplazas _hubo_ por _existió_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Habla el texto de enfermedades que surgían con frecuencia, es decir, habitualmente.  Y después, habla de una sola que surgió (una vez) dentro de unas cuantas que iban surgiendo.  Efectivamente, es una acción que interrumpe otra.

Comment: Así que, ¿se podría decir que "hubo" tiene el significado de "surgió" en este contexto? Y, por cierto, si se hubiese referido a la existencia de esta enfermedad infecciosa, ¿se podría haber dicho "Si bien las enfermedades infecciosas eran causa común de muerte en la Edad Media, existía una que marcaba récords."?

Comment: @x1704e Haces unas preguntas que me hacen dudar a mí como nativo. Enhorabuena :). Creo que se podría decir bien así, aunque no se porqué no me suena del todo bien. Yo hubiera usado _existió una que marcó..._. Pero sí, lo que comentas parece correcto

Comment: Si te suena más natural lo que dijiste, es lo que usaré :-)